# How to put two underbraced "tabular" tables side by side?

Tags: tables, align

This code:

```tex
    Relations $r, s:$
    \[\underbrace{\begin{tabular}{||c c||}
                \hline
                A        & B \\ [0.5ex]
                \hline \hline
                $\alpha$ & 1 \\
                \hline
                $\alpha$ & 2 \\
                \hline
                $\beta$  & 1 \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}}_{r}\] & \[\underbrace{\begin{tabular}{||c c||}
        \hline
        A        & B \\ [0.5ex]
        \hline \hline
        $\alpha$ & 2 \\
        \hline
        $\beta$  & 3 \\
        \hline
        \hline
    \end{tabular}_{aaa}\]
```

leads me to `Misplaced alignment tab character &.LaTeX` error.

If I remove `&`, tables are not aligned, so, uh. How can I do this?

[image]

*Please dont make the solution overcomplicated, I only use LaTeX as a distraction while reading my lecture notes. Asking only for visual pleasure.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using displayed maths (`\[...\]`), those form a line of their own, so are not doing what you intend. Replace them by inline maths (`$...$` or `\(...\)` whichever form you prefer).

The misplaced alignment tab character is the `&` you put between the two `tabular` environments. Since that's outside any alignment that's just wrong, remove it.

The `:` inside of `$...$` in your first line gives the wrong spacing, use `$r, s$:` instead.

There might be other things one could visually improve, but "please don't make the solution overcomplicated", so here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Relations $r, s$:

$\underbrace{\begin{tabular}{||c c||}
    \hline
    A        & B \\ [0.5ex]
    \hline \hline
    $\alpha$ & 1 \\
    \hline
    $\alpha$ & 2 \\
    \hline
    $\beta$  & 1 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}}_{r}$ 
$\underbrace{\begin{tabular}{||c c||}
    \hline
    A        & B \\ [0.5ex]
    \hline \hline
    $\alpha$ & 2 \\
    \hline
    $\beta$  & 3 \\
    \hline
    \hline
\end{tabular}}_{aaa}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You might also consider using `array` instead of `tabular`. The biggest difference is that in `array` each cell is in maths mode, so you don't need the `$...$` around `\alpha`, etc. If you don't want the `A` and `B` turn italic (maths) you could use `\mathrm{A}` and `\mathrm{B}` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Relations $r, s$:

$\underbrace{\begin{array}{||c c||}
    \hline
    A      & B \\ [0.5ex]
    \hline \hline
    \alpha & 1 \\
    \hline
    \alpha & 2 \\
    \hline
    \beta  & 1 \\
    \hline
\end{array}}_{r}$
$\underbrace{\begin{array}{||c c||}
    \hline
    A      & B \\ [0.5ex]
    \hline \hline
    \alpha & 2 \\
    \hline
    \beta  & 3 \\
    \hline
    \hline
\end{array}}_{aaa}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am going for the first option as my brain prefers tabular lol.